# Get AccessToken for Azure Storage from InteractiveBrowserCredential

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-identity

I'm trying to get an accesstoken from a InteractiveBrowserCredential so I can make calls to the Azure Datalake, but when I try to do this I get this error message:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not
> indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make
> sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including
> the signature.).'

Below is my code, I sspect it might be the scopes I request but I have tried every value I could find online (https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation, https://storage.azure.com/.default).

```
// setup authentication
var tenantId = "common";
var clientId = "xxx";               
var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions {
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,       
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

// authenticate and request accesstoken
var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
var token = interactiveCredential.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://storage.azure.com/.default" }));

// Create HttpClient            
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Token); ;
string res = await client.GetStringAsync("https://xx.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list"); // this line throws the error
textBox1.Text = res;
```

If I use the SDK it does work, so it does not appear to be security settings.

```
// connect to Azure Data Lake (this works fine)
string accountName = "xxx";
string dfsUri = "https://" + accountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";
var dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), interactiveCredential);

// get filesystems 
var systems = dataLakeServiceClient.GetFileSystems().ToList();// works fine
```

Comment: Your request is missing some of the required headers mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2#request-headers. I think it is `x-ms-version` header that is giving you 403 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error *"**`403`** Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signatureerror"* usually occurs if you have not **`x-ms-version`** header in your code.

I agree with Gaurav Mantri, To resolve the error make sure to pass **`header value`**.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below in Postman:***

[image]

I generated the access token by using the below Parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:4b08ee93-f4c8-47e9-bb1e-XXXXXXX
client_secret:client_secret
scope:https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code: code
```

[image]

When I included **`x-ms-version=2019-02-02`**, I am able to access the storage account successfully like below:

[image]

The **`x-ms-version`** header value must be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

In your code, you can include the header below samples:

```cs
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02");
```

```cs
request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02");
```

**Reference:**

[Versioning for the Azure Storage services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services)

Comment: Excellent thank you, it was indeed required headers and the error message not being very helpful.